# Query result count is 0

Tags: vb.net, linq

I wonder why this query has an empty result list, both DataTables have entries. I think that the concatenation of the fields may be the problem but I can't find a similar example.

```
Dim query = (From a In DT_Nachricht.AsEnumerable() _
             Join b In DT_Nachricht_filter.AsEnumerable() _
                 On (a.Field(Of String)("land") & a.Field(Of String)("tel") & a.Field(Of String)("ort")) _
                 Equals b.Field(Of String)("land_tel_ort") _
             Select New With _
             { _
                 .land = a.Field(Of String)("land" + "tel" + "ort"), _
                 .tel = b.Field(Of String)("land_tel_ort") _
             }).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here: `a.Field(Of String)("land") & a.Field(Of String)("tel") & a.Field(Of String)("ort")`

Try:

```
Dim query = (From a In DT_Nachricht.AsEnumerable() _
         let land = a.Field(Of String)("land") & a.Field(Of String)("tel") & a.Field(Of String)("ort")
             Join b In DT_Nachricht_filter.AsEnumerable() _
                 On land Equals b.Field(Of String)("land_tel_ort") _
             Select New With _
             { _
                 .land = land, _
                 .tel = b.Field(Of String)("land_tel_ort") _
             }).ToList()
```

Comment: I tried this but it has not resolved my problem. The count is still 0.